# Custom Block Not Rendering on Checkout Cart

Tags: magento2, cart

I want to add a custom block  **Below Order Total** using a knockout template but unable to render it on the checkout cart page.

Here I have done so far.

**1) checkout_cart_index.xml at**

> app/code/Ishaq/CheckoutTotal/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="fee" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Ishaq_CheckoutTotal/converted_rate</item>
                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Ishaq_CheckoutTotal/converted_rate</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>

                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**2) converted_rate.html at**

> app/code/Ishaq/CheckoutTotal/view/frontend/web/template/converted_rate.html

```
<!-- ko -->
<div>My Converted rate goes here</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**3) converted_rate.js at**

> app/code/Ishaq/CheckoutTotal/view/frontend/web/js/converted_rate.js

```
define(
    [
        'Ishaq_CheckoutTotal/js/converted_rate'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** If you want it without using a knockout you can use this

**app/code/Ishaq/CheckoutTotal/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.totals.container">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="checkout.cart.custom.block" after="-" template="Ishaq_CheckoutTotal::custom-block.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Ishaq/CheckoutTotal/view/frontend/templates/custom-block.phtml**

```
<div>My Converted rate goes here</div>
```

**OR**

**2.** If you want use knockout you can do this

**app/code/Ishaq/CheckoutTotal/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.totals.container">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="checkout.cart.custom.block" after="-" template="Ishaq_CheckoutTotal::custom-block.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="ordersummary" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Ishaq_CheckoutTotal/js/custom-block-order-summary</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Ishaq/CheckoutTotal/view/frontend/templates/custom-block.phtml**

```
<div id="order-summary-block" data-bind="scope:'ordersummary'">
  <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "#order-summary-block": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
           "components": {
                "ordersummary": {
                    "component": "Ishaq_CheckoutTotal/js/custom-block-order-summary",
                    "config": {
                        "data1": "some data",
                        "data2": "some other data"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**app/code/Ishaq/CheckoutTotal/view/frontend/web/js/custom-block-order-summary.js**

```
define([
'ko',
'uiComponent',
'mage/url',
'mage/storage',
],function (ko, Component, urlBuilder,storage) 
{
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {template: 'Ishaq_CheckoutTotal/custom-block-order-summary',},
        initialize: function(config) {
            this._super();
            var data1 = config.data1;
            var data2 = config.data2;
        },
    });
});
```

**app/code/Ishaq/CheckoutTotal/view/frontend/web/template/custom-block-order-summary.html**

```
<!-- ko -->
<div>My Converted rate goes here</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```